# How Adobe Analytics collect the geolocation variables (cities or country) through Tealium?

Tags: geolocation, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I would like to know what is the process once a user login into an app. I am trying to figure out the process between the app, Tealium and Adobe Analytics.
I really appreciate your help.

I was checking on Tealium and Charles what is the variable that populates that information but I didn't know what to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The data from the Adobe Analytics Geo Location reports are not directly collected client-side via javascript (or android/ios sdk if using native mobile app), so you won't see them in the collection server requests in Charles Proxy (or other http sniffing tool).

When a given http(s) request is made to the collection server, the visitor's IP address is sent by the browser/device itself in the http(s) request headers (this information is sent on a browser/device level so servers know where to send responses back to, in general).

The collection server references the IP address from the request header and uses lookup tables to determine Geo Location info by IP address to populate the Geo Location reports.